# How to write neatly with pen and paper?

Tags: pens

A while ago, I decided to learn to type with 10 fingers, rather than 2 (two index fingers).

**I followed a strict prescription of how to place the hand, and where to place each finger, etc.**
I learned how to type with 10 fingers, which has significantly improved my typing.

Now I am considering to also improve my writing efficiency/effectiveness regarding the more ancient art of written words (pen and paper).

**Is there some method, some set of prescriptions for how to place the hand and move the fingers, for writing neatly, clearly, and quickly with pen and paper?**

Comment: What are you hoping to try to write? Calligraphy? Just ink drawing in general or something different. The craft you are trying might be important here.

Comment: Writing methodology will really depend on several things, none of which you've mentioned here - firstly, what are you writing? Is this everyday writing (like notes, or in a journal) or something decorative that needs to be "pretty". Who needs to be able to read this writing? Do you want to learn print writing (letters are disconnected) or cursive writing (letters flow into each other)? Are you right or left handed? - Believe it or not, the method differs between the two. It might help to add an image of your current writing and what you're hoping for.

Comment: This page has some good advice: http://www.artofmanliness.com/2014/12/16/improve-your-cursive-handwriting/

Answer (score 3):

My daughter has Cerebral Palsy and writes quite well thanks to a few tricks she learned from an Occupational Therapist.

1. Get a fat pencil or you can get a plastic sleeve that goes over a pencil.
2. Use a soft pencil lead available in many stores, especially art stores.  I recommend HB, or 2B.  It is easier to control a soft pencil.
3. Rest your forearm on a table when writing, not just the palm of your hand for better control.

This works for anyone, not just folks with physical issues.  Now that I am getting older, this works for me, too. Once your brain gets the message, these tricks become less important.

Answer (score 2):

The old practice, practice and practice some more, practice makes perfect.
Different schools will teach different methods of holding the pencil or pen, and how to hold your hand. Those last two have to work together, if you alter one without altering the other your writing may suffer.

If you still remember what your teacher at school have told you, keep doing that. Improve on it by doing it often and for some time each day. Writing for half an hour each day will do much more for your writing than even the best advice.
Get the writing instruction book or exercise book your school used, so you go back to what you were taught when you were learning to write, specially the level when you were 10 year old or so.

If you do not remember what you were taught in school, you might look for a primary school teacher in your area to freshen up your mind.
Or get instructions in calligraphy, but in person rather than online, so your teacher can correct your position as well as tell your what you are supposed to do. And do go for a simple style of writing which feels natural to you rather than the more intricate styles.